# Need to add an ArrayFormula for this formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula, formula, array-formulas

I need to wrap this into an ArrayFormula but it's giving me an error, how do I add an arrayformula for this?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( IF(ISNUMBER(A2:A), INDEX(Backend!C2:C100&" "&Backend!D2:D100&" "&Backend!E2:E100&" - Ref "&Backend!A2:A, MATCH(MIN(ABS(Backend!K2:K100-A2:A)), ABS(Backend!K2:K100-A2:A), 0)),""))
```

> Error #N/A Message: Array arguments to MINUS are of different size.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9XXv.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

I tried searching similar problem to my case but most of them were not relevant or i couldn't find them.

Answer (score 0):

The error message “Error #N/A Message: Array arguments to MINUS are of different size” usually occurs when you try to subtract two arrays that have different sizes.

The formula you provided uses the MINUS function which subtracts two numbers or two arrays.
The error message suggests that the arrays you are trying to subtract have different sizes.  You can try checking if the arrays have the same number of rows and columns

Comment: When you mean sizes? you mean the range?